# Develop in .Net to Palm OS

Tags: .net, palm, palm-os

It's possible to develop in .Net to build apps to a Palm OS device like a Palm T|X, because i'm a Visual Basic developer, not a .Net, but i'm studing to develop in .Net, because is a better language, but i'm using the Handheld Basic ++ and the NSBasic to develop for my Palm, but if i can develop in .Net it will be better, but if it's impossible, someone can post please, a link or post here a good tutorial of: How to develop an application that uses a database using NSBasic 4.4 or the Handheld Basic. Thanks! And sorry about my english!

Comment: .NET isn't a language: It's a framework. .NET has multiple languages in it; such as Visual Basic.NET, C#, et. al.

Comment: I know, but i can develop to Palm OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In, short: no you can't

Longer: Wellcome to the "real" world. .Net technology is not cross platform.

Comment: You should say: the leading .NET *implementation* is not cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly to the Palm OS since it is a Linux variant.  There used to be a application called [AppForge Crossfire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppForge)  but it has not been in production for a few years.  You could also look into Java programming for the Palm OS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your one and only chance to do what you're after doesn't exist - yet.

What you (would) want is [Mono, which provides an OSS CLR to run your .Net binaries on](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page).  You'll also have to develop with something that provides a cross-platform interface, which means you won't be able to whip up something in Visual Studio and just plunk it down on the device.

However, Mono doesn't run there yet, and I don't think Microsoft has any plans to provide outside platforms direct support.  So, you're not going to get "there" from "here", without a major effort in porting something like Mono to your platform.